# how do I access the phone camera from a non-flash web app

Tags: jquery, mobile, web, camera, webcam

I want to create a web application that will allow visitors to take pictures with their computers webcam or mobile phone camera. Is this possible to build using only one type of technology and if so, how can it be implemented, i.e. I assume it would need to be non flash based to work with mobile phones. What sort of technology could this use?

I have come across this: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera - are there any other recommended libraries / APIs I could use?

Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest you to change the question title to something like "how do I access the phone camera from a non-flash web app"

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

The "Round 1" works for all Androids over 3.0.